# How to Customize SecureSocial 3.0 Views?

Tags: playframework-2.0, securesocial

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703517/securesocial-3-0-m3-custom-login-view-with-play-2-3-9)

I have the same implementation. Not only it does not work, but in debug, I never even enter this code!

```
object MyRuntimeEnvironment extends RuntimeEnvironment.Default[BasicUser] {
    override val userService: UserService[BasicUser] = new SlickUserService
    override lazy val authenticatorService: AuthenticatorService[BasicUser] = new AuthenticatorService[BasicUser](
      new CookieAuthenticatorBuilder[BasicUser](new SlickAuthenticatorStore, idGenerator),
      new HttpHeaderAuthenticatorBuilder[BasicUser](new SlickAuthenticatorStore, idGenerator)
    )
    override lazy val viewTemplates: ViewTemplates = new CustomTemplatesController(this)

}
```

and

```
class CustomTemplatesController(env: RuntimeEnvironment[_]) extends ViewTemplates {
  implicit val implicitEnv = env

  override def getLoginPage(form: Form[(String, String)],
                            msg: Option[String] = None)(implicit request: RequestHeader, lang: Lang): Html = {
    //securesocial.views.html.login(form, msg)(request, lang, env)
    views.html.custom_login(form, msg)(request, lang, env)
  }

  override def getSignUpPage(form: Form[RegistrationInfo], token: String)(implicit request: RequestHeader, lang: Lang): Html = {
    securesocial.views.html.Registration.signUp(form, token)(request, lang, env)
  }
}
```

I guess my only choice left is to copy paste controllers from secureSocial github code and change the templates called...

any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the custom environment to your controllers?

Comment: Probably right on spot, but since the question I made some custom facebook OAUTH2 login. :D Hopefully it'll help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the play framework to load your environment config. Usually this is done by creating a Module (assuming MyRuntimeEnvironment is defined in package called Service):

```
package modules;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import securesocial.core.RuntimeEnvironment;
import service.MyRuntimeEnvironment;

public class EnvironmentModule extends AbstractModule{

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        MyRuntimeEnvironment environment = new MyRuntimeEnvironment();
        bind(RuntimeEnvironment.class).toInstance(environment);
    }


}
```

The in your application.conf:

```
play.modules.enabled += "modules.EnvironmentModule"
```

This should bootstrap your customised environment configuration and load your custom templates.